# How to specify path to `.pxd` file in Cython

Tags: cython, include-path

My project has the following directory structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── pxd
├── pyx
│   ├── Landscaping.pyx
│   ├── Shrubbing.pxd
│   └── Shrubbing.pyx
└── setup.py
```

However, if I move `Shrubbing.pxd` anywhere else, say, into `pxd/`, I get the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import pyx.Shrubbing
cimport Shrubbing
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pyx/Landscaping.pyx:2:8: 'Shrubbing.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import pyx.Shrubbing
cimport Shrubbing

cdef Shrubbing.Shrubbery sh
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is strange because in `setup.py` I have:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules=cythonize([
    Extension(
        'pyx.Landscaping',
        sources=["pyx/Landscaping.pyx"],
        include_dirs=['pxd']), # <-- HERE
    Extension('pyx.Shrubbing', sources=["pyx/Shrubbing.pyx"])
]))
```

which clearly specifies the new directory for `Shrubbing.pxd`.

The source files are all very short, but to avoid cluttering this post, I will just post a link to a repository: https://github.com/lobachevzky/landscaping

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`include_dirs` is for C/C++ headers, not Cython `pxd` files.

In general it is best to keep related `pyx/pxd` files together in same directory, ie Shrubbing.pyx and Shrubbing.pxd should be in same directory.

To then use that from *other modules*, include a `__init__.pxd` and `cimport` via the name used in the Extension, eg `pyx.Shrubbing` as you would with Python modules.

If importing in python (not `cimport`), `__init__.py` should be included as well.

When using in the same module, OTOH, the `.pxd` needs to be available at runtime of that module, which means including it in *Python* search path.

If you want to organise the pxd files into separate dirs then link them symbolically within the module directory to make them available to the module, the dir containing an `__init__.pxd` or `.py` file.

It's a bit messy as Cython does not currently support relative imports, hence the need for linking when wanting to import from another dir.

See [documentation for more details](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=include_dirs#configuring-the-c-build).

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for, but what do you mean by 'link them within the module directory'? Is that a `cimport` statement or do you actually mean with a symbolic link?

Comment: @ethanabrooks Symbolic link, yes.

Comment: I don't think a symbolic link is necessary. In the [Cython docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#search-paths-for-definition-files), as long as you include the `__init__.pxd` in the directory where your `.pxd` is located, Cython will search your path for the definitions file when you use `cimport` in an implementation, `.pyx` file. I've used this to create some linear algebra wrappers, which I import in project specific cython implementation files. So just make sure the `.pxd` file is in a directory that's in your path, e.g., by setting PYTHONPATH

Comment: Per the answer, symbolic links are only necessary `If you want to organise the pxd files into separate dirs`, meaning from where the module directory containing `__init__.pxd` resides.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this answer is broader than the specific question you are asking.  It is more "how do you share `pxd` definitions between packages".

To sort this out for myself, I created a [cython_example](https://github.com/jkleckner/cython_example) repo.  It is not satisfying because it uses the old `distutils` tools rather than `setuptools` to prevent `zip/egg` from encapsulating the underlying files but may shed some light here.  I'm actively looking for an improvement that will work with the automatic extraction of code from `egg` files so that `setuptools` can be used.

The core idea is to use the `os.path.dirname(from_package.__file__)` to use to add to the include path.  See the [setup.py](https://github.com/jkleckner/cython_example/blob/master/landscaping/setup.py#L12) file.

**Update**:

The `cython` [email list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cython-users/8yfrEkAn6g8/T3JIYzB3CgAJ) provided the hint that using `zip_unsafe` when installing using `setuptools` would make everything work.  See the [updated working example](https://github.com/jkleckner/cython_example) and the [update I added](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/2184) to the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=include_dirs#configuring-the-c-build) .

Comment: So danny, the other answerer, indicated that `include_dirs` is for header files, not `pxd ` files. Do you disagree with that assertion?

Comment: If you don't zip the files, the ordinary include mechanisms of (python,cython) work and don't require `include_dirs` to be used.  So in a way, he is correct in that you need to manually add dirs to the path that won't be found by python dependencies that are rooted in a non-zip directory.  I will update my repo to reflect that.

Comment: From the [actual documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=include_dirs#configuring-the-c-build):

`The Extension class takes many options, and a fuller explanation can be found in the distutils documentation. Some useful options to know about are include_dirs, libraries, and library_dirs which specify where to find the .h and library files when linking to external libraries.`

Comment: From same documentation: `Note also that if you use setuptools instead of distutils, the default action when running python setup.py install is to create a zipped egg file which will not work with cimport for pxd files when you try to use them from a dependent package. To prevent this, include zip_safe=False in the arguments to setup().`

Comment: `include_dirs` has nothing to do with either `cimport` or `.pxd` files. See documentation as linked above.

Comment: @danny Thank you for linking the documentation.  I was the one who created that patch for the documentation.  ;-)