# derive class from from sklearn.cluster.KMeans with cython

Tags: scikit-learn, cython

I like to create a child class of scikit-learns's `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` and would like to do this in cython for performance reasons. Is this possible?

There is an old issue https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2057 which seems to be related and indicates the (non-)publication of pxd-files. Deriving in cython from one the main classes in sklearn would really be useful, however, so I ask here if there is now any solution.

My source file:

```py
from sklearn.cluster cimport KMeans
cimport cython
@cython.cclass
class OtherKMeans(KMeans):
    def __init__(self,kappa, **kwargs):
        self.kappa = kappa
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

my setup file `setup1.py`

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(
   ext_modules=cythonize("otherkmeans.pyx"),
   compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}
)
```

Result of calling

```
python setup1.py build_ext --inplace
```

is

```
src> python setup1.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling otherkmeans.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing otherkmeans.pyx
/home/miller/miniconda2/envs/bkm9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /home/musk/new-k-means/src/otherkmeans.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sklearn.cluster cimport KMeans
^
------------------------------------------------------------

otherkmeans.pyx:1:0: 'sklearn/cluster.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sklearn.cluster cimport KMeans
^
------------------------------------------------------------

otherkmeans.pyx:1:0: 'sklearn/cluster/KMeans.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from sklearn.cluster cimport KMeans
cimport cython
@cython.cclass
class OtherKMeans(KMeans):
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

otherkmeans.pyx:4:18: First base of 'OtherKMeans' is not an extension type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miller/new-k-means/src/setup1.py", line 4, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize("otherkmeans.pyx"),
  File "/home/miller/miniconda2/envs/bkm9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1127, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/home/miller/miniconda2/envs/bkm9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1250, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: otherkmeans.pyx
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: pxd file should be included. See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14847, if one is not included you probably should submit a bug report.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57697577/5769463

Comment: Thx. I have looked in /home/miller/miniconda2/envs/bkm9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/ but the only pxd file there was _k_means_common.pxd. Is there any way I need to modify my setup file to find those files? Where are they supposed to be?

Comment: I think your assumption, that there is a cluster.pxd is wrong. The class ist not exported and cannot be reused.

Comment: I was actually hoping for kmeans.pxd so that I could cimport KMeans

Answer (score 1):

`KMeans` looks to be [a regular Python class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/93359b645d1c47e3c787821cf276ec486451dcac/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py#L1126). That means you can't use it as the first base for a `cdef class` (you can actually derive a `cdef class` from it with it as a second/third/etc base though).

You can compile regular (i.e. non-cdef) classes in Cython. Their functions are still sped up by Cython. The limitations are:

- they aren't generated as a C struct so you can't get fast access to C defined members,
- they can't have `cdef` member functions (but if you care about this you might be able to use global `cdef` functions instead... Remember though, the `cdef` is mainly a calling convention - a regular function is *still* sped up by Python).

Therefore you should ask yourself "do I actually need a `cdef`/`cython.cclass` class?" and the answer is probably "no".