# setup.py with cython compilation in namespace package: *.pxd not found

Tags: python, deployment, cython, setup.py, cythonize

I am packaging a project involving cython extensions inside a namespace package. My folder structure looks as follows

```
.
├── namespace_package
│   └── package
|       ├── extension.pxd
|       ├── extension.pyx
│       └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

My setup script looks as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension

# factory function
def my_build_ext(pars):
    # import delayed:
    from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

    # include_dirs adjusted: 
    class build_ext(_build_ext):
        def finalize_options(self):
            _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
            # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
            __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
            import numpy
            self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

    #object returned:
    return build_ext(pars)

extensions = [Extension(namespace_package.package.extension, ['namespace_package\\package\\extension.pyx']]

setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext' : my_build_ext},
    setup_requires=['cython', 'numpy'],
    install_requires=['cython', 'numpy'], 
    packages=['namespace_package.package'],
    ext_modules=extensions
)
```

Here, I used the tricks to delay the import of `numpy` and `cython` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117786/add-numpy-get-include-argument-to-setuptools-without-preinstalled-numpy), and my solution is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361418/how-to-specify-path-to-pxd-file-in-cython) solution.

The problem is that `extension.pxd` is not found or processed. That is, declarations made in `extension.pxd` are not available and I get the corresponding errors.

How do I do the setup properly so that all files are found and processed?

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules

Comment: Actually this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502296/5769463 already provides the answer, but one has to follow the link to github.

Comment: @ead Thanks for the helpful links. It may be a worthwhile alternative to distribute the c files only. I will investigate further.